# Error on sql insert statement (not because of primary key)

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, null

I facing with this following error;
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Dogrulama', table 'logodb.dbo.ASC_Sayim'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The statement has been terminated."

My sql query, and parameters are like:

```
SqlCommand kayitSorgu = new SqlCommand();
kayitSorgu.Connection = logodbDatabaseConnection;
kayitSorgu.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ASC_Sayim (PaketNo,StokKodu,StokAdi,Lot,Ambar,CoralGozukenAdet," +
    "SayimAdet,Tarih,SayimNo,GerekenIslem,GerekenIslemMiktar) Values " +
    "(@PaketNo,@StokKodu,@StokAdi,@Lot,@Ambar,@CoralGozukenAdet,@SayimAdet,@Tarih,@SayimNo," +
    "@GerekenIslem,@GerekenIslemMiktar)";

kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaketNo", Form1.degiskenler.PaketNo);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StokKodu", Form1.degiskenler.StokKodu);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StokAdi", Form1.degiskenler.StokAdi);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lot", Form1.degiskenler.Lot);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ambar", Form1.degiskenler.Ambar);
//kayitSorgu.Parameters.Add("@Dogrulama", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Dogrulama;
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dogrulama", Form1.degiskenler.Dogrulama);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoralGozukenAdet", Form1.degiskenler.CoralGozukenAdet);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SayimAdet", SayimAdet);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tarih", tarih);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SayimNo", Form1.degiskenler.SayimNo);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GerekenIslem", gerekenIslemKodu);
kayitSorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GerekenIslemMiktar", GerekenIslemMiktar);

kayitSorgu.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My insert code is at Form2.
I'm getting some values from a public class named as 'degiskenler' at Form1.cs and some others from Form2 as local variables.

DB table's columns are like

```
ID  int identitycol IDENTITY
PaketNo varchar(20) 
StokKodu    varchar(20) 
StokAdi varchar(20) 
Lot varchar(20) 
Ambar   varchar(20) 
Dogrulama   varchar(10)
CoralGozukenAdet    numeric(18, 2)  
SayimAdet   numeric(18, 2)  
Tarih   datetime    
SayimNo varchar(10) NULLABLE
KontrolDurumu   varchar(10) NULLABLE
GerekenIslem    bit NULLABLE
GerekenIslemMiktar  numeric(18, 2)  NULLABLE
```

I can insert value if i set related column as 'NULLABLE' but this time, for that record, 'dogrulama' column's value becomes 'null'.

I'd changed my parameters for 'Dogrulama' column like this, but nothing changed.

```
kayitSorgu.Parameters.Add("@Dogrulama", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Dogrulama;
```

And also tried using local variable, and changing dogrulama variable's data type as int (numeric), but couldn't succeed.

Why this error occured for 'dogrulama' column? And how can i handle it?
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: If you don't want the value to be null, then what *should* it be?

Comment: Your SQL doesn't refer to Dogrulama anywhere... I think it should!

Comment: @roryap, actually i want not be null, i just tried for find where is the problem.

Comment: @Jon, thanks, ouch  big mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're SQL command does not contain the `Dogrulama` column, and thus it's taking the default value, which is `NULL` since the column allows nulls and does not explicitly provide a default value.

Adjust your query like this (note the addition of `Dogrulama` column in the column list and `@Dogrulama` in the values list):

```
"INSERT INTO ASC_Sayim (PaketNo,StokKodu,StokAdi,Lot,Ambar,CoralGozukenAdet," +
"SayimAdet,Tarih,SayimNo,GerekenIslem,GerekenIslemMiktar,Dogrulama) Values " +
"(@PaketNo,@StokKodu,@StokAdi,@Lot,@Ambar,@CoralGozukenAdet,@SayimAdet,@Tarih,@SayimNo," +
"@GerekenIslem,@GerekenIslemMiktar,@Dogrulama)";
```